# php created image not showing

Tags: php, html, image

I try to create a simple image with php and want to display it on a HTML site.

I open the file with an image tag and linked it right.

If i open the php image itself via the site's sourcecode I only see a single white square.

Many Thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Hello </title>
  </head>
  <body style=background-color:white>

<img src="includes/Images/hello.php" alt="">

Above is my image
</body>
</html>

<?php
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$image = imagecreate(2000,2000);
$background = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
$foreground = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);

imagestring($image, 5,5,1, "Test", $foreground);

imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Comment: The php script seems to generate the image OK so it seems likely that the path `includes/Images/` is not correct.

Comment: your foreground is set to 255, 255, 255 - which is white! - that's why you see a white image

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. If if I change the color I still see the white square. On the HTML page it looks like the img tag is completly ignored. The sample text sticks to the page top. And the links is correct. I used the same link in multiple other occasions for images from the same dir.